# Deshabilitar botón formulario PHP

Tags: php, javascript

Tengo una pequeña aplicación que me ejecuta un archivo `.bat` que hace copias de seguridad. Quiero que cuando pulse el botón de `Iniciar copia`, ese botón se deshabilite mientras se ejecuta el `.bat`. He intentado con esta línea pero ni lo deshabilita, ni manda el formulario:

```
<input type="submit" name="copia" value="Iniciar copia" onClick="this.disabled='disabled'" />
```

Aquí les dejo mi código entero:

```
  <?php
      session_start();

      if (isset($_SESSION['correcta']) && $_SESSION['correcta'] === true) {
        if (isset($_POST["copia"])){
          $dia = date("w");
          switch ($dia) {
            case '1':
              exec('start /B C:\Users\Usuario\Desktop\backupcopia.bat');
              echo "<body style='text-align: center;'>
                      <h1 style='margin-top: 10%;'>Copia Lunes realizada</h1>
                      <br>
                      <br>
                      <form class='' action='logout.php' method='post'>
                              <input type='submit' name='cerrar' value='Cerrar'>
                      </form>
                    </body>";
              exit();
              break;
            case '2':
              exec('start /B C:\Users\Usuario\Desktop\backupcopia.bat');
              echo "<body style='text-align: center;'>
                      <h1 style='margin-top: 10%;'>Copia Martes realizada</h1>
                      <br>
                      <br>
                      <form class='' action='logout.php' method='post'>
                              <input type='submit' name='cerrar' value='Cerrar'>
                      </form>
                    </body>";
              exit();
              break;
            case '3':
              exec('start /B C:\Users\Usuario\Desktop\backupmiercoles.bat');
              echo "<body style='text-align: center;'>
                      <h1 style='margin-top: 10%;'>Copia Miercoles realizada</h1>
                      <br>
                      <br>
                      <form class='' action='logout.php' method='post'>
                              <input type='submit' name='cerrar' value='Cerrar'>
                      </form>
                    </body>";
              exit();
              break;
            case '4':
              echo "<body style='text-align: center;'>
                      <h1 style='margin-top: 10%;'>Copia Jueves realizada</h1>
                      <br>
                      <br>
                      <form class='' action='logout.php' method='post'>
                              <input type='submit' name='cerrar' value='Cerrar'>
                      </form>
                    </body>";
              echo '<pre>';
              $ultima_linea = system('C:\Users\Usuario\Desktop\backupcopia.bat', $retval);
              echo '
                </pre>
                <hr />Ultima linea de la salida: ' . $ultima_linea . '
                <hr />Valor de retorno: ' . $retval;
              exit();
              break;
            case '5':
              exec('start /B C:\Users\Usuario\Desktop\backupcopia.bat');
              echo "<body style='text-align: center;'>
                      <h1 style='margin-top: 10%;'>Copia Viernes realizada</h1>
                      <br>
                      <br>
                      <form class='' action='logout.php' method='post'>
                              <input type='submit' name='cerrar' value='Cerrar'>
                      </form>
                    </body>";
              exit();
              break;
          }
        }
      } else {
        header('Location: index.php');
        exit();
      }

    ?>
    <html lang="es" dir="ltr">
      <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Copia de seguridad</title>
        <style >
          body{
            text-align: center;
          }

          h1{
            margin-top: 10%;
          }
        </style>
      </head>
      <body>
        <h1>Copia de Seguridad</h1>
        <br>
        <form action="" method="post">
          <input type="submit" name="copia" value="Iniciar copia" onClick="this.disabled='disabled'" />
        </form>
      </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: ¡Hola @Xerox / @xerox_12! ¿Te puedo reestructurar tu código y la forma en la que mandas el backup para poder llevar a cabo lo que deseas hacer?

Comment: @OscarGarcia Claro! Por supuesto!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El problema principal que sufres es que nada más pulsar el botón de envío del formulario deshabilitas el botón, pero inmediatamente después se envía el formulario poniéndose en blanco la página irremediablemente mientras se hace el backup y se muestra el HTML de backup terminado.

Hay dos soluciones a tu problema:

#### Forzar el envío de HTML parcial

Aunque hay trucos para que se muestre un HTML parcial mientras se completa una tarea larga en PHP, no son recomendables porque su buen funcionamiento depende de muchos factores como la configuración de la pila TCP, que el navegador pueda mostrar HTML parcial, que algún proxy intermedio (tanto de tu proveedor como del usuario que accede a la página) no envíe el contenido hasta haber sido completado, la configuración de compresión de la página o el uso de `ob_start()`, etc.

Ejemplo de cómo hacerlo de esta manera:

```
<h1 id="mensaje">Cargando</h1>
<?php
/* Forzamos el envío parcial del contenido al navegador */
ob_end_flush();
flush();
/* Simulamos un trabajo de 10 segundos */
sleep(10);
?><script>
/* Modifcamos el texto anterior indicando que el trabajo ha finalizado */
document.getElementById('mensaje').innerText = 'Proceso finalizado';
</script>
```

#### Haciendo uso de peticiones XHR

Sin embargo lo mejor y más compatible es que hagas una [petición XHR](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest) para obtener el PHP y mientras se completa la carga deshabilites el botón:

En tu formulario inicial:

```
<form id="formulario">
  <input type="submit" name="copia" value="Iniciar copia" id="copia" />
</form>
<script>
  let copia = document.getElementById("copia");
  function completado() {
    copia.disabled = false;
    copia.value = this.responseText;
  }
  document.getElementById("copia").addEventListener("click", function (e) {
    /* Evitamos que se envíe el formulario */
    e.preventDefault();
    /* En su lugar enviamos una petición XHR */
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.addEventListener("load", completado);
    /* Dos eventos útiles adicionales:
    xhr.addEventListener("error", function_error);
    xhr.addEventListener("abort", function_abortado); */
    xhr.open("GET", "hacercopia.php?copia");
    xhr.send();
    /* Deshabilitamos el botón y mostramos un texto */
    copia.disabled = true;
    copia.value = 'Realizando copia de seguridad';
  });
</script>
```

En tu PHP de destino:

```
<?php
/* Ahora estamos mandando la orden por GET, no por POST */
if (isset($_GET["copia"])){
/* ... */
case '1':
  exec('start /B C:\Users\Usuario\Desktop\backupcopia.bat');
  /* El mensaje que aparecerá en el botón al finalizar debe ser texto, no HTML */
  echo "Backup finalizado con éxito";
  exit();
  break;
/* ... */
```

Ese mensaje enviado con el `echo` será el que se envíe a la función para que se muestre dentro del botón.

#### Versión con jQuery

Para facilitar el trabajo del desarrollo de la petición XHR se puede hacer uso de jQuery de la siguiente manera:

```
<form id="formulario">
  <input type="submit" name="copia" value="Iniciar copia" id="copia" />
</form>
<script>
  let copia = $("#copia");
  $( "#copia" ).click(function(e) {
    /* Evitamos que se envíe el formulario */
    e.preventDefault();
    /* En su lugar enviamos una petición XHR */
    var jqxhr = $.ajax({
      method: "POST",
      url: "hacercopia.php",
      data: {
        copia: 'si',
      }
    }).done(function(texto) {
      copia.prop('disabled', false);
      copia.val(texto);
    }).fail(function() {
      copia.prop('disabled', false);
      copia.val('Se produjo un error');
    });
    /* Deshabilitamos el botón y mostramos un texto */
    copia.prop('disabled', true);
    copia.val('Realizando copia de seguridad');
  });
</script>
```

Comment: cuando haces referencia a `hacercopia.php` a que te refieres? Y otra pregunta, ¿será compatible con Internet Explorer?

Comment: Al nombre de tu PHP que hace la copia. No pusiste el nombre del archivo en la pregunta. Sí, a partir de la versión 7 Internet Explorer implementó la clase `XMLHttpRequest`. Anteriormente había que crear una clase `ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP")`.

Comment: Vale, el nombre del archivo era `copia.php`. Lo voy a probar y te comento

Comment: ¿Usas jQuery? Con jQuery quizá se quede más limpio el código y, además, implementa internamente cualquier diferencia entre navegadores, incluso antiguos.

Comment: ¿Como podría hacerlo con jQuery?

Comment: No me funcionó. Hace la copia de seguridad pero no se deshabilita el botón

Comment: Tengo que hacerte unas preguntas para ver el origen del problema.
 [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/88448/discussion-between-oscargarcia-and-xerox).

Comment: Perfecto, vamos a ello